# How to do precedence with multiple exponentials, ^, in an arithmetic equation

Tags: java, math, postfix-notation, infix-notation, exponential

I am working on a program that solves arithmetic equations.  I have encountered a problem that occurs when there are multiple exponential statements in a row the program does not correctly solve them. An example would be: 2^3^2, the correct answer is 512 but the program outputs 64.  This is because the program does 2^3 and then 8^2, instead of doing 3^2 and then 2^9.  Let me know if you have any ideas on how to modify my current code or have something to add.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import myUtil.*;

public class PostFixEvaluator extends Asg6
{
    public static class SyntaxErrorException extends Exception
    {
        SyntaxErrorException(String message)
        {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    private static final String operators = "+-*/^()";
    private AStack<Double> operandStack;

    private double evaluateOP(char op) throws Exception
    {
        double rightside = operandStack.pop();
        double leftside = operandStack.pop();
        double result = 0;
        if(op == '+')
        {
            result = leftside + rightside;
        }
        else if(op == '-')
        {
            result = leftside - rightside;
        }
        else if(op == '*')
        {
            result = leftside * rightside;
        }
        else if(op == '/')
        {
            if(rightside == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Can not divide by 0, the equation is undefined");
            }
            else
            {
                result = leftside / rightside;
            }
        }
        else if(op == '^')
        {
            result = Math.pow(leftside, rightside);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean isOperator(char ch)
    {
        return operators.indexOf(ch) != -1;
    }

    public double evaluate(String exp) throws Exception
    {
        operandStack = new AStack<Double>();
        String[] tokens = exp.split("\\s+");
        try
        {
            for(String nextToken : tokens)
            {
                char firstChar = nextToken.charAt(0);
                if(Character.isDigit(firstChar))
                {
                    double value = Double.parseDouble(nextToken);
                    operandStack.push(value);
                }
                else if (isOperator(firstChar))
                {
                    double result = evaluateOP(firstChar);
                    operandStack.push(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid character: " + firstChar);
                }
            }
            double answer = operandStack.pop();
            if(operandStack.empty())
            {
                return answer;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Syntax Error: Stack should be empty");
            }
        }
        catch(EmptyStackException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Syntax Error: The stack is empty");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Most computer languages have a *rightward* associative `^` (which would result in the same answer as your program). Parenthesis are normally used to specify precedence to override the standard [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) (hint: key term). The other approach to obtain the desired behavior is to make the `^` operator *leftward* associative.

Comment: The "most simple" way I have of making the given program rightward associative is to do the calculation *on the way out* of the tree - that is, `evaluatorOP` should use *recursion* to find `rightside` before it is used. (But then you'll need to find a way of keeping the stack able to be consumed which will result in a larger redesign.)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an *LL(1)* grammar (which is what a recursive descent parser can parse) to model a right-associative operator (`^`). A right-associative operator requires left recursion, which doesn't work so easily with *LL(1)* grammars. You'll want to look at left factoring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Left_Factoring

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with operator Priorities as you might want to have them anyway.
For testing i changed the class a bit, so i could test it and its sure not most efficient or readable but you should get
the idea how it works.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

import java.util.*;

public class PostFixEvaluator
{
    public static class SyntaxErrorException extends Exception
    {
        SyntaxErrorException(String message)
        {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    private static final String operators = "+-*/^()";
    private static int[] operatorPriority = {1,1,2,2,3,10,10};
    private Stack<Double> operandStack;
    private Stack<Character> operatorStack;

    private double evaluateOP(char op) throws Exception
    {
        double rightside = operandStack.pop();
        double leftside = operandStack.pop();
        double result = 0;
        if(op == '+')
        {
            result = leftside + rightside;
        }
        else if(op == '-')
        {
            result = leftside - rightside;
        }
        else if(op == '*')
        {
            result = leftside * rightside;
        }
        else if(op == '/')
        {
            if(rightside == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Can not divide by 0, the equation is undefined");
            }
            else
            {
                result = leftside / rightside;
            }
        }
        else if(op == '^')
        {
            result = Math.pow(leftside, rightside);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean isOperator(char ch)
    {
        return operators.indexOf(ch) != -1;
    }

    public double evaluate(String exp) throws Exception
    {
        operandStack = new Stack<Double>();
        operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();
        String[] tokens = exp.split("\\s+");
        try
        {
            for(String nextToken : tokens)
            {
                char firstChar = nextToken.charAt(0);
                if(Character.isDigit(firstChar))
                {
                    double value = Double.parseDouble(nextToken);
                    operandStack.push(value);
                }
                else if (isOperator(firstChar))
                {
                    // Try to evaluate the operators on the stack
                    while (!operatorStack.isEmpty())
                    {
                        char tmpOperator = operatorStack.pop();
                        // If Operator has higher Priority than the one before,
                        // Calculate it first if equal first calculate the second
                        // operator to get the ^ problem fixed
                        if (operatorPriority[operators.indexOf(firstChar)] >= operatorPriority[operators.indexOf(tmpOperator)])
                        {
                           operatorStack.push(tmpOperator);
                           // Operand has to be fetched first
                           break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            double result = evaluateOP(tmpOperator);
                            operandStack.push(result);
                        }
                    }
                    operatorStack.push(firstChar);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid character: " + firstChar);
                }
            }

            // Here we need to calculate the operators left on the stack
            while (!operatorStack.isEmpty())
            {
                char tmpOperator = operatorStack.pop();
                // Operator Priority has to be descending,
                // or the code before is wrong.
                double result = evaluateOP(tmpOperator);
                operandStack.push(result);
            }

            double answer = operandStack.pop();
            if(operandStack.empty())
            {
                return answer;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Syntax Error: Stack should be empty");
            }
        }
        catch(EmptyStackException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Syntax Error: The stack is empty");
        }
    }

    // For testing Only
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        PostFixEvaluator e = new PostFixEvaluator();
        System.out.println(e.evaluate("2 ^ 3 ^ 2"));
    }

}
```